# Tweet An Update Using C# TweetSharp With New OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, twitter, tweetsharp

I don't suppose anyone has used the latest version of TweetSharp to do a twitter status update, I was using the old version and now getting a bit lost with this OAuth stuff and cannot get it to work.

I'd just like some example code of using it to do a simple status update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This URL will provide the example you need to get your head around OAuth: http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserGuide&referringTitle=Documentation

From there, there's a method on TwitterService called SendTweet which should be fairly straightforward. Once you have an access token, you can do it like this:

```
var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);
service.SendTweet("I'm totally tweeting!");
```

Comment: I simply can't get OAuth to work for twitter i simply keep getting a 401.

Comment: Its how to authorise your own website to auto tweet thats stumped me

Comment: Feel free to hit up our discussion forum for guidance. But basically, you need to obtain an access token (you can do this now from Twitter's application settings area, or do it in code) for your server, and then save those credentials in your web.config for reuse at runtime.

Comment: This answer points to a non existent link. There is also no available discussion forum

Comment: Open source projects come and go. If you are still looking for how to do this you can check the GitHub for the surviving project, http://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Comment: Deprecated - Updated solution: var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret); service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);
service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions{Status = "I'm totally tweeting!"});